# How to disable the clicksToMoveEditor feature of the RowEditing plugin?

Tags: grid, extjs4

I don't want to move the editor while one row is editing, I had set the clicksToMoveEditor property to 10 for my purpose, but it still can move the editor.

How to reach this goal in ExtJS 4.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just override the startEdit function so that it only works if the editor is not currently editing.

```
Ext.define('CustomRowEditor',{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing',
    startEdit: function(){
        if(!this.editing){
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    }
});
```